# Debuggin in Laravel

Tags: php, api, debugging, laravel-5.3

I would like to learn debugging in Laravel using the following situation.

I am following [this](http://baljeetsingh.in/blog/series-build-an-app-with-laravel5-backend-and-angularjs-frontend-part-1-480/) tutorial. I need the output like below of this line  "*Now try to hit the route, /api/v1/jokes, you will get an error token not provided like this:*"

But I am getting output like below

[image]

How can I debug this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

In this situation your best solution would be to check the list of all registered routes in Laravel.

```
php artisan route:list
```

If you don't see your /api/v1/jokes, you've lost it in your routes files.

Generally, I'd recommend using a PHP debugger, like xdebug: https://xdebug.org/

It's usually installed as a PHP extension and used with some modern IDEs

Comment: Addition: laravel.log in /storage/logs contains information about occured exceptions